# Unexpected Symbol - CS1525

Tags: c#

there is an error in `int simpleArraySum(int[] ar)` :

```
solution.cs(10,26): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `,', `;', or `='
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

I've tried adding `static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar)` and deleting `static void Main(string[] args)`, but in that case no Main. 
I tried also = in this line, but no helping. I think that will be some easy thing, but I don't know.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        int simpleArraySum(int[] ar)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i=0; i< ar.Length; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + ar[i];
            }

            return sum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can, @Guy , just shouldn't, at least not in this case.

Comment: @LuccaFerri Not before C# 7.0

Comment: @Thomas Schremser version wasn't specified so I have considered the latest. Besides, he would have received CS8059 + the syntax error if it wasn't compatible.

Comment: Please try to write a more descriptive Title, that will also make it easier for people to find out IF they can answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a syntax problem, as you forgot to close the scope.

Working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int simpleArraySum(int[] ar)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + ar[i];
            }

            return sum;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(simpleArraySum(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
    }
}
```

Added a '}' at the end to close the scope, and added a `Console.WriteLine` to show the function's return.

---

***Update***

As some comments pointed out, you would need C# 7.1 + to use a method inside another. If you don't have this compiler version, you could try taking the method out of the Main, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + ar[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(simpleArraySum(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
    }
}
```

Before:

```
| static void Main
|____ int simpleArraySum(int[])
|____ calls simpleArraySum which is in scope
```

After:

```
| static int simpleArraySum(int[])
| static void Main
|____ calls simpleArraySum which is a static method
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it should work, but hackerrank doesn't accept it. :(

Comment: @foreigner do you know the compiler version? You could try to remoe the int method from the Main function. Updating the answer with how it could also be done.